# Did Jack steal the Heart of the Ocean?

Tags: titanic

In [Titanic (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120338/?ref_=nv_sr_1), towards the end after the ice berg accident, Rose decides to go back and tell her mother and fiance about it to warn them. "Now that one of my missing items has returned, I know where to find the other" and at that point, Jack is searched and found to have a Diamond in his coat pocket (a coat in which he had "borrowed" earlier).

We see Rose ask Jack to put the diamond back in the safe after he is done drawing her in the nude while wearing it. It seems obvious that he has stolen it, but if that is the case, why? An easy answer is that because he is a poor boy with a 3rd class ticket, he has plenty of reason. I believe this to be too easy of an answer and don't quite think he has stolen it at all, but has been framed or simply "borrowed" the wrong jacket. But, since he acquired the jacket before he met with rose to draw her, we know the diamond was not at that point missing.

So, did Jack really steal the Heart of the Ocean diamond necklace?

Comment: I think you missed many scenes of film.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Jack didn't steal the necklace. Rose put both the necklace and a letter in the safe for Cal to find. Later on, in order to lock away Jack for theft, Cal's butler slips the necklace into Jack's jacket for the guards to find.

Comment: ... and at the end, we see Rose as an old woman toss the Heart of the Ocean off the rear of the research ship.

Comment: Yeah I missed some important parts, didn't I?

Comment: @DustinDavis - It's a horrendously long movie. It happens :)

Answer (score -1):

How could Jack have stolen it either way...as far as I could see he didn't know the combination of the safe. Could someone clarify this for me? And to answer your question, no. Jack most definitely did not steal the Heart of the Ocean necklace. It was put in his pocket by Cal's valet Lovejoy, as is seen in the movie.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. We aren't a forum.